# Rails - Ajax do not work properly on production server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a very strange problem in my Ruby on Rails application. I have some controller that looks like this:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  #rest of the code

  def get_password
    @password = @report.password
  end
end
```

In my views I have this code:

```
%small{id: "report_password_#{report.id}"}
  %span= link_to '[Show Password]', get_password_report_path(report), remote: true
```

and I also have very simple get_password.js.erb file:

```
$("#report_password_<%=@report.id %>").html('<%= @password %>')
```

And now the problem is that on localhost everything works ok but after deploying to production when I click link Show Password it sometimes work, sometimes not...

When I made 2 fast clicks on link it will show the password. When I click on link application sends properly ajax request and get proper response but do not properly update div with password.

Do You have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Any errors in JS console? Any timeout?

Comment: Unfortunately no... Ajax requests works properly but jQuery sometimes didn't update div.

Comment: What if you remove `tubrolinks`?

Comment: I remove include ActionController::Live and now everything works as expected. But the problem is that I must have ActionController::Live for other actions. I have no idea how to solve this problem...